# Latex find formatted text and print it at the end of document

Tags: macros, highlighting, code

I am currently coding my interview transcripts for qualitative research by highlighting sentences in different colours (using `soul` and `xcolor` packages).

So, I want to print all text which belong to the same code at the end of my document, i.e. all texts which were highlighted, say, in green. How could I do this?

I'm using the following commands:

```
\newcommand{\hlc}[2][yellow]{ {\sethlcolor{#1} \hl{#2}} }

\newcommand{\kod}[2]{%
    \marginpar{#1} \IfStrEqCase{#1}{%
        {genre}{\hlc[YellowGreen]{#2}}%
        {amer}{\hlc[Plum]{#2}}%
          % plus other codes %
        }[\PackageError{kod}{Undefined option to kod: #1}{}]%
}%
```

thus in text I have `\kod{genre}{blahblahblah}` for example. Now I'd like to make LaTeX collect and print all `blahblahblah` for all instances where `\kod{genre}{}` is used. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

etoolbox might help you, this very simple example is made using hooks. you could modify it to fit your needs

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\newcommand{\yellow}[1]{{\sethlcolor{yellow}\hl{#1}}\gappto{\yellowhook}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\section{main text}
test1 \yellow{test2} test3
\section{yellow words}
\yellowhook
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There are a couple of unwanted spaces in your code