# Automatic mark my text with margin braces without using box

Tags: mdframed, brackets, braces, marginnote, tikzmark

I use the `tcolorbox` or `mdframed` advantages for several months to mark my text automatically, according to [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina) tips in question [Automatic margin curly braces text on multiple pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267474/automatic-margin-curly-braces-text-on-multiple-pages?rq=1). But I would like to go beyond disadvantages, and I come back to the community.

What are my problems? Firstly, the `decoration` TikZ library offers limited choice of braces or some to complex learning. Secondly, if I want to cut within a sentence or a paragraph, the use of boxes makes two or three paragraphs (one before, the box and one after), and I don't want that. But `schemata`, `minipage`, `mdframed`, `tcolorbox` etc. use boxes and cut my sentences & paragraphs when I mark inside.

Here is what I like:

1. simplicity & flexibility of the `\}` use — or `)` `\]`, `\langle`, `Vert`…—  like in the [Andrew Swann](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/15925/andrew-swann) answer to the [Big brackets around text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110391/big-brackets-around-text/120155#120155) question (It would be ideal for me to use braces, brackets or parens as in music or in old editions, but I know, it's difficult to combine typographic quality & lengths management), or better;
2. ingenuity of `\tikzmark` for pointed mark in a text, like in the [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) basic usage in [Margin notes with a pointing arrow…](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78193/margin-notes-with-a-pointing-arrow-that-are-automatically-vertically-adjusted) article;
3. usefulness of four display modes developed by `mdframed` or `tcolorbox` packages: a single page, or first part, middle part, last part [mentioned in the previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267474/automatic-margin-curly-braces-text-on-multiple-pages?rq=1);
4. use of margin notes in odd page & even page.

I imagine we would build a function that combines the brace use `\}` (or something like musixtex braces) and the `\tikzmark{}` or `\pgfmark{}` if I don't need `TikZ`. In this way, with counter, I mark my text like that \mark{Note}{Text}. If text crosses pages, I imagine that something like  `finaltextmark` and `begintextmark` exist in LaTeX. A dreamed example :

```
\newcounter{mark}\newcommand\complexmark[2]{\setcounter{mark}{0}% counter null
  \tikzmark{\thecounter}% mark one
  \marginnote[{\{}#2]{{\}}#2}% the margin note & brace between mark \tikzmark{1} & \tikzmark{1}, how?
  #1% the texte. if we meet a end page before the mark two, end the brace & open other one in te next page
  \tikzmark{\thecounter}}% mark two end.
```

I illustrate my problems here. Thanks.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = arara
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}% no-math for musixtex
\usepackage{multido,xparse,lipsum,schemata,marginnote}
\usepackage{musixtex}\instrumentnumber{3}\akkoladen{{2}{3}}\setstaffs14
\usepackage{changepage}\strictpagecheck
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,decorations.pathreplacing,tikzmark}\tikzset{remember picture}
  % methode 2
\newsavebox{\leftbox} \newsavebox{\rightbox}
\NewDocumentCommand{\lrboxbrace}{s O{\{} O{\}} O{0.1\linewidth} m O{0.8\linewidth} m}{% \lrboxbrace[<lbrace>][<rbrace>][<lwidth>]{<ltext>}[<rwidth>]{<rtext>}
  \begin{lrbox}{\leftbox}\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\begin{varwidth}{#4}#5\end{varwidth}}{\begin{minipage}{#4}#5\end{minipage}}\end{lrbox}
  \begin{lrbox}{\rightbox}\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\begin{varwidth}{#6}#7\end{varwidth}}{\begin{minipage}{#6}#7\end{minipage}}\end{lrbox}
  \ensuremath{\usebox\leftbox\left#2\,\usebox\rightbox\,\right#3}}
  % method 4
\NewDocumentCommand \margincallout {O{} m m +m }{% \margincallout{<mark1>}{<mark2>}{<note>}
\marginnote{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node [anchor=west, text width=\marginparwidth, align=left, font=\small,#1]  at (0,0) {#4}; 
  \draw[->] (-0.5,1.94) -- (pic cs:#2); \draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (pic cs:#3);\draw[decoration=brace,decorate,thick] (-0.3,1.94) -- (-0.3,0); \end{tikzpicture}}}
  %method 5 
\newtcolorbox{tcbdecor}[1]{%\begin{tcbdecor}{<note>}<text>\end{tcbdecor}
  colback=white, boxrule=0pt, colframe=white,  arc=0pt,  outer arc=0pt,  top=0pt,  bottom=0pt,%
  check odd page,breakable,enhanced jigsaw,oversize,%
  overlay={\ifoddpage\draw[decoration={brace,mirror},decorate] (frame.north east) -- node[rotate=90,above=4pt] {#1} (frame.south east);%
  \else\draw[decoration={brace,mirror},decorate] (frame.north west) -- node[rotate=90,above=4pt] {#1} (frame.south west);\fi}}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{1}\textsc{Quality and variety of brackets}%
\marginnote{\startextract \emph{Stylish}\zendextract}
\paragraph{MusiX\TeX}\emph{I love typographic quality (9/10) and resizing of curly brackets (2 choices), but I don't know how to use them for text. Look this graceful brackets in margin:}
\paragraph{savebox} \emph{I like the simple use (5/10) on the code of typographic bracket signs (more than 5 choices): [square], (round), {\{}curly{\}}, <angle>, or |vertical bars||. But…}

\lrboxbrace[\Vert][{)}]{\emph{I'm Grouchy Smurf}}{\emph{… it doesn't cross pages and cuts my sentences !} \lipsum[2]}

\paragraph{schemata} \emph{I like (5/10) the use of braces, brackets and parens (3 choices) with the schemata package and his simplicity. But…}

\schema[close]{\emph{… it doesn't cross pages and cuts my sentences !} \lipsum[2]}{\noindent{\emph{This is why\\I don't like boxes}}} %

\paragraph{2}\textsc{Don't cut sentences and cross pages}%
\paragraph{tikzmark} \emph{I discover tikzmark, and I like the fonctionnement. But… I don't want to use the TikZ decorates, I find them (some choices) misfit (3/10). If we can mark the \textbf{beginning}\tikzmark{a} and the end of a page with tikzmark, we save the \emph{cut sentence} problem. (What you see on the sidelines is not so bad) But we stay with two problems:\begin{itemize}
\item how manage cross pages and vertical length?
\item how put the (good) bracket between beginning and \textbf{end}\tikzmark{b} marks in (good) margin?
\margincallout{a}{b}{Tikzmark with marginpar or marginnote doesn't cut anything! But length, automate, insert a good brace, crossing pages without box… seems difficult.}
\end{itemize}}

\paragraph{mdframed, tcolorbox} \emph{I like crossing pages with mdframed or tcolorbox, but…}
\begin{tcbdecor}{I don't like TikZ decorates}\emph{… if it crosses pages, it continues to cut sentences ! I hope you understand my problems, and if if you find something to help me, I would be very happy. Thank you very much!}\
\lipsum[1]\end{tcbdecor}
\end{document}
% arara: xelatex
% arara: xelatex
% arara: xelatex
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am not quite able to see what you mean here. Could you possibly elaborate or add som images to explain better?

Comment: @RunarTrollet I just edit it to be clearer. My english is bad, sorry

Comment: I think this is far too much to be answered in an answer here. You're asking for a new package, basically, which needs to be considerably more flexible than several sophisticated current options.

Comment: @cfr Thank you for your analysis. I better understand my difficulty.